# Long critical notes in reledmac: text does not flow to next page

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, octavo

I'm writing a manuscript with reledmac and I have long critical notes. My critical notes are set as PARAGRAPH -- see my MWE. I cannot see a way to have the text of a long note flowing to next page. This is not a problem with familiar notes. And all goes well in critical notes if I avoid the [paragraph] argument. But I need to have the notes arranged as a paragraph, which is the usual way to set the layout of the kind of text I'm writing. Please see below also the workaround that I use, nesting a second series of critical notes on the same lemma, which I can use for longer texts spanning more than one page. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 11pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
This is normal text with a long footnote.\footnote{\blindtext[3]}
 \beginnumbering

   \pstart
    \begin{footnotesize} 
   This is \edtext{\textbf{critical}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{This is a critical foot note} } text with critical \edtext{\textbf{notes}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{And this is a critical foot note with long text. \blindtext[3]} } .
\blindtext[1]
\end{footnotesize}
\pend
\endnumbering
And this is again normal text.
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Workaround using nested critical notes:

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 11pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{normal}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
This is normal text 
 \beginnumbering

   \pstart
    \begin{footnotesize} 
   This\footnote{This is a familiar note} is \edtext{\textbf{\edtext{critical}{\Bfootnote{This is a B footnote on the same lemma, and \blindtext[1]}}}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{This is a critical foot note} } text with  \edtext{\textbf{critical \edtext{notes}{\Bfootnote{And this is another B footnote on another lemma and \blindtext[2]}}}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{And this is another critical foot note. } } .
\blindtext[1]
\end{footnotesize}
\pend
\endnumbering
And this is again normal text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It it is a knew limitation of paragraphed footnotes, they can't contain page break inside.... No knew solution today.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any workaround or any alternatives? As of now, I'm manually checking which notes are two longs and breaking them in two. Not an elegant solution!

Comment: no, sorry... If would have found a workaround, it will have been implemented in the package...

Comment: I did not know you are the maintainer of reledmac. Such a great package. And thanks for answering!

Comment: I found a workaround for my purpose. Just wanted to confront with you, if you think it is a good idea or if I can instead get into worse issues. I thought of nesting a second level of critical notes, so that I can keep shorter comments in a paragraph arrangement and use this second series for longer comments, in a normal arrangement so they can flow to next page as needed. Please see my MWE. Thanks

Comment: I updated the original question

Comment: I think it is a good idea, yes.

Comment: @Haim please post as an answer and then tick it if you solved your question, helps keep the site clean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since paragraphed footnotes cannot contain page break inside, this is a workaround in which longer notes are in a second series:

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 11pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{normal}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
This is normal text 
 \beginnumbering

   \pstart
    \begin{footnotesize} 
   This\footnote{This is a familiar note} is \edtext{\textbf{\edtext{critical}{\Bfootnote{This is a B footnote on the same lemma, and \blindtext[1]}}}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{This is a critical foot note} } text with  \edtext{\textbf{critical \edtext{notes}{\Bfootnote{And this is another B footnote on another lemma and \blindtext[2]}}}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{And this is another critical foot note. } } .
\blindtext[1]
\end{footnotesize}
\pend
\endnumbering
And this is again normal text.

\end{document}
```